# I am having trouble making my page responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a project that I'm working on and in the quotes section I'm trying to make it responsive so that when the screen size's width is `1160px` or less the .box div has a `47.5%` width, and when the screen size's width is `900px` or less the .box div has an `85%` `width`. Here is my code, and any help is appreciated:

```css
    * {
       box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
       margin-left: 25px;
       margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    
    .body {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
       min-height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .container {
       position: absolute;
       /* width: 1100px; */
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
       margin: 20px;
    }
    
    
    .container .box {
       position: relative;
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
       width: 31.5%;
       height: 420px;
       margin: 20px 10px;
       background: #121e27;
    }
    
    .container .box .content {
       padding: 30px;
       text-align: center;
    }
    
    .container .box .content .quote {
       max-width: 48px;
    }
    
    .container .box .content p {
       color: white;
       padding: 20px 0;
    }
    
    .container .box .content .user {
       max-width: 72px;
       border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    .container .box .content h3 {
       color: #33d1a0;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       font-size: 16px;
       letter-spacing: 1px;
       font-weight: 600;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 1160px) {
       .container .box {
          width: 47.5%;
       }
    }
    
    
    @media (max-width: 900px) {
       .container .box {
          width: 85%;
       }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qj2CjE3LjnO8P25iSJTGPKwCD3NdTxUF/view?usp=drive_open">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium tempore eius laborum ut commodi itaque illum aspernatur porro consectetur nobis?</p>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="user">
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="quotes.png">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium tempore eius laborum ut commodi itaque illum aspernatur porro consectetur nobis?</p>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="user">
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="quotes.png">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium tempore eius laborum ut commodi itaque illum aspernatur porro consectetur nobis?</p>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="user">
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="quotes.png">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium tempore eius laborum ut commodi itaque illum aspernatur porro consectetur nobis?</p>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="user">
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="quotes.png">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium tempore eius laborum ut commodi itaque illum aspernatur porro consectetur nobis?</p>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAeFBMVEX///8AAAClpaX8/Pz39/e3t7fZ2dm9vb3T09Pl5eXw8PBfX1/h4eFtbW1qamqbm5vMzMyCgoJ4eHgaGhqKioplZWWrq6sPDw/FxcUwMDDs7OySkpJ/f38UFBQhISFLS0s8PDxPT09XV1c2NjY4ODinp6dEREQpKSmYua94AAAGb0lEQVR4nO2d6XbiMAyFMUsIW8O+lhZoB97/DYc0MIQkkEiWkNzx97uL70kiy9pcq3k8Ho/H4/F4PB6Px+PxwOiug+Gy3V4uw063Ib0YaoL5+25r0qzeomFTellEBNHePGA1Wjr/MDvT7SN5F2ZD6TXaMPwskffD9o/0OrG0V1X0/bBx8ZMcnirri4mk1wul2wPpO/MRSq8ZxByqL2YsverqNMAPMGHSl155RfplG8RjWtJrr0QLrc+48aZGNgKNOUivv5SRnUBjdsr9uLGtwPO20ZUW8QwCgWeTqtjBsX5FEz7Uvqiofb6IT2klDxhSCdS6aazpBBqj8kD1QanQBNJy8hBZmStbaT05CD/ChHdpRVkW1AqNsvPihlyg+ZDWdEeHXqAxdWlVaWYcCo0i763PItBspHXdeONRaNT4p6TeTBo1ns2US6Eac8ol0BglOY0ln8KBtLaEAZ9CI60tgVGgjteU3OdOM5JWF8NmSWNUWNMdp0KjILTYZBVoltL6arWAV6EC39QqEVPOTFofy9k3zUpaH+9+HyN/vtgzK5Q3phNmhR1pgaw+W4x8yI1bofyGyK2wLS2QXaF8eYZXaMvvf0vlLQ19SuYe+d3ii1mh/I6PrNKrjLzXRlJC8wR5z7vOK/BLWh9rPDhGQUyYJTl6Q0P9N+92oSEkzGtM5Q0Ns6k5SquLYUpxJygIJtZ44xg6ir8YExdKar9CPoVTaW0XYB1OEOTd7oQ/XALV1Ao3uBTKn36vMNmak7SuG0w5RPkQzQ2WBJSCtFMKDoUanO4bDHnSnrSmDJW6tkHIB2juIa9PnEsrykHWEpSgsQ+R9iSsqAL6BqV7quPUlIXwU5RPOBVDVjykIcBWDFHsVF1DUIo2hUAFZVBPIJD4Jq2hBOt6Wp3to2kszY1eI3NjbbMvat0mMqCbhBauDDfB+qgKMmkZ+q1o8HncnVa52HvniBCYC1q0j6fv47E3nYcS+ZnMFLbcWQf8GN+zKoL0IK3Tiye7rTe51vRV1ldugGI3h+wX2MhX5g5eFtYID4WLzDV/NCsHGXu5o0Sx5zB5ybG4X6wv/v+54p5mVCUvNc5Z0ObDrtsF/3by9LmM899KWDKJYNbO/87TsNaRN5cRliXti+Lw4aPRkN/TZcFRfv3gp//B6fZUmAE1Kw4/dNqbt1Q47ms2agXFP1khaX5gM6vVyp+eW4Nm8+ny+pXK5CZMkcaqztgn/kupan0Xa0Jd/wC0jgxwGiFVHQxPEVahB9fYgA1625KHG8GD5g4gD6QDTkHuiAViju6TqOKDbLQwWQ/aYEAXsYKYY1R64uu2sGNDSN2bPXIRZyajom39QhBhjllXCA2qbbHFbjwPMsavcfYB9pZ/lq7oDfuOZjj1xqNNVN9MxwOi7miyowZ3sToeol2Ruc7ZBqLwOHdHhQ0kWTjmZm07SFLF3G0/dhA0Dal+hMbs7RXylVbSYP0lKjakCdbmdC+toBTLPZG5I4YCy8AU63gdGhZ2CnVvFQlWGwZjGT4dVqUb79Krr4SNQvw9Dq/E4jVlnpBEhUXfieVNDq/CoqafvvCXB3SQna1ThBp01E29T3oFXcThgENzAauQd14gJcgPkXleICXID9EJly0B6bgxz4OgZIdTyD1NjxJcZp971hwluGiN9KohoEyNI253Asr5Vh4ovQcV+2YeTEoMRqHenFoRmNKMb+lFg0BUiDtzdEpA9H0TpbZfBeJSGoe80hjEdkHSpPU6EJ3fDvndMYjKE3cO+D8grhjgnhZIDfx04daGj9ny3QnSJMBDNS6dDmPgJ0TpFUOBtwxJrxgKeOKSY24pwjF1KFiaAI5jsN0WxwX4FjoHykzuARed/H6FrDM7OQDPAfUK1QE+AnuF6vj9CsHf4e/fLRwLJmL6Z6RXDAU+zdWFytI08BPww9EJSoHHaRyLJk7AAv+DmLdj2wWmYj83gkY1mGIMN2q8ryAE8t7VTA2u7Et61RBwxewOFWMgR3875Jpiy6BLBiDpAd365EzcG3+HAvEEay5s2p330ouvhE2PpRPGxu6SCAeqamyvhFJfg2k/ElT5KYpirrJq/zQ3jhJFR2+fJdmAGqV9CSfCscNLjZE34nv11BXyDcin7jXrmp5jfqorCeG7jkKpWYtxanJQH4iOc9n2NkP+odCNTtie11/OvDXsa7shyePxeDwej8fj8Vz4C1b2gkr4izi5AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" class="user">
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="quotes.png">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium tempore eius laborum ut commodi itaque illum aspernatur porro consectetur nobis?</p>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="user">
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="quotes.png">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium tempore eius laborum ut commodi itaque illum aspernatur porro consectetur nobis?</p>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="user">
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I tried your code out and it seems to be doing what you want. You don't say what you want to happen at over 1160px but at that point the .container{width:31.5%;} from your CSS applies. I always use min-width not max-width in my media queries and work from small to large width because it seems more logical to me.

Comment: @user3425506 I added a screenshot of how it looks like ↑

Comment: Aren't they 47.5% of the width of their container? I thought that was what you wanted. I can't see from the screen shot what width the container is.

Comment: They are 47.5%, but the width is less than 800px, so they are supposed to be 85%
But thanks anyway, I received an answer below that I will try out right now.

Answer (score 1):

better use `min-width:` or `max-width:` to determine the maximum and minimum of the screen size for example like the following one

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){
 /* styles */
}
```

or use one of the depend on how you do calculations of the screen size likewise when you use `min-width`

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
 /* styles */
}
```

or use `max-width`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
 /* styles */
}
```

and the following are the types of media queries

```
/* Smartphones (portrait) ---------- */
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
 /* styles */
}
/* Smartphones (landscape) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 321px){
 /* styles */
}
/* Tablets, iPads (portrait and landscape) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){
 /* styles */
}
/* Tablets, iPads (portrait) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
 /* styles */
}
/* Tablets, iPads (landscape) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
 /* styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 1224px){
 /* styles */
}
/* Large screens ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 1824px){
 /* styles */
}
```

and those media queries are for the `screen` only not for the `print` so if you want to apply the properties to all you can not define `screen` or if you want to apply it on `print` you can define it as well

Comment: I tried your method, but for some reason, nothing changes. I fail to see what the problem is. The two media queries have the exact same code (except for the max-width and styles of course), yet only one of them works. I am deeply puzzled .

Comment: you should use it in sensitive case otherwise you will get an error for example you can't use portrait and landscape for the same media and also give the different properties also it is not to unaccept answer